# Wordpress page-menu-option

Tags: wordpress

Hello i want help in this code

```
`add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_menu_page' );
```

function register_my_custom_menu_page(){
    add_menu_page( 'custom menu title', 'custom menu','my-menu-slug2' ,'manage_options',  'custompage', 'my_custom_menu_page', plugins_url( 'myplugin/images/icon.png'

```
), 8 );
//add_submenu_page("my-menu-slug2", "My Submenu", "My Submenu", 0, "my-submenu-slug", "mySubmenuPageFunction");
 //add_submenu_page("my-menu-slug2", "My Submenu2", "My Submenu2", 0, "my-submenu-slug", "mySubmenuPageFunction");
```

}`

`function my_custom_menu_page(){
    echo "Admin Page Test"; 
}`

when i add "my-menu-slug2" in add-menu-page the menu will disappear and i want to add sub pages. ere in sub menu a parameter is 0 after sub menu name "My Submenu2" if add it in main menu then it will appear but the position will not work  it will appear in the bottom
can anyone please help

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
add_menu_page('My Custom Page', 'My Custom Page', 'manage_options', 'my-top-level-slug');

add_submenu_page( 'my-top-level-slug', 'My Custom Page', 'My Custom Page', 'manage_options', 'my-top-level-slug', 'mySubmenuPageFunction');

add_submenu_page( 'my-top-level-slug', 'My Custom Submenu Page', 'My Custom Submenu Page', 'manage_options', 'my-secondary-slug', 'mySubmenuPageFunction');
```

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page

Comment: The code you send me this is working but tell who i can add position i want it above the appearance menu